# Make text appear below the center image

Tags: css

I want the "Hello World" text to appear exactly below the image on the website.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8zqptLx/).

```
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/W8lz0xc.png?1">
<p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is the `img` set as `absolute` and stretched to the whole screen?

Anyways if you just remove the `position: relative` from the `div` element, you will get the text below the image.

Answer (score 1):

Position the whole thing rather than just the image

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #FEEDDA;
  ;
}
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/W8lz0xc.png?1" />
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fc5zem6q/)

Answer (score 0):

Made a fiddle here.

You just need to use CSS to center the elements.

```
text-align:center;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7g0horha/

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to have an absolute positoned `<p>` tag. Muck around with the `margin-top: -50px` style to suit your needs.

Here you go:

[Center aligned text](http://jsfiddle.net/m8zqptLx/12/)

Put the following code on your `<p>`

```
p{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no need to use positioning at all. Just think of it being a table.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: table;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#FEEDDA;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>    
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/W8lz0xc.png?1" />
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```